# dataTransfer.getData is empty even after dataTransfer.setData is called, does it have to do with fetch()?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get data from essentially an online excel spreadsheet. Previously, I was retrieving this data from the actual HTML DOM elements and their children, using .innerText or .value. I realized that this would be inconsistent, since the excel spreadsheet can have more or less rows depending on what the user wants. I changed up the way I get data by using querying the database that the spreadsheet is stored in. This way, it wouldn't matter how many columns this spreadsheet has, I can retrieve only the data I want from the columns in the database.

I made sure that the data I am retrieving from the database is valid, the data presented to dataTransfer.setData() is the exact same as before when I was retrieving information from DOM elements, and the object I am trying to transfer is indeed a string. When I step through from onDragStart() to onDrop(), it seems like either dataTransfer.setData isn't actually setting the data, or dataTransfer.getData isn't actually getting the data, which seems very unlikely. The only thing I can think of is that I introduced a fetch statement, and am trying to set the data in the promise of the fetch, which might make things weird for some reason.

BEFORE:

```
function onDragStart(e) {
    let data = {
        "item": e.target.children[2].children[0].value,
        "description": e.target.children[3].textContent,
        //etc...
    };
    let stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', stringData);
}

function onDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let stringData = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    let data = JSON.parse(stringData);
    //do things with data...
}
```

AFTER:

```
function onDragStart(e) {
    fetch('<my_url>', {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(data)})
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            let parsedResult = JSON.parse(result);
            let transferData = {
                'item': parsedResult.item,
                'description': parsedResult.description,
                //etc...
            };
            let stringData = JSON.stringify(transferData);
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text', stringData);
         });
}

//onDrop() did not change
```

The transferData object in the second onDragStart() is the exact same as the first data object in the first. When I step through the onDrop(), I noticed that stringData is empty, so an error is thrown when trying to JSON.parse(), "unexpected end of JSON input."

Comment: `e.dataTransfer.setData` is called asynchronously once the fetch has received the response. so it could very well be possible that this hasn't happened yet when `onDrop` is called

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay that makes sense to me, is there any way I can still use fetch but also get the data when I need it?

Comment: @JaromandaX I figured out a workaround. Instead of passing the data that came back from the database in the dataTransfer, I simply transfered the values I needed to perform the fetch, and then performed the fetch in the onDrop() function

Comment: That would make sense